# Whats the easiest way to remove null values from an array with a loop (Js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, null

If I have an array with three text values and two null values. How could those be removed with a loop. Is it possible to use splice to do this.

```
arrayVal[0] = null
arrayVal[1] = "Some text"
arrayVal[2] = null
arrayVal[3] = "More text"
arrayVal[4] = "Text Again"
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
arrayVal[0] = "Some Text"
arrayVal[1] = "More text"
arrayVal[2] = "Text Again"
```

Comment: Look into the `splice()` function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
arrayVal.filter(Boolean);
```

Note that Boolean will remove any falsy value, that includes zero, empty string, null, undefined.

Comment: `function(x){return x!=null}` wouldn't be that hard to write as well

Comment: Perfect, simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved with a `for` loop;

```
function removeNull() {
    var arrayVal, newArrayVal, j;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayVal.length; i++) {
        j = 0;
        if (arrayVal[i]) {
            newArrayVal[j] = arrayVal[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```